# Wire up Elm lang and Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, html, functional-programming, semantic-ui, elm

How easy is it to use ready-made jQuery plugins in Elm? I'm just starting to learn Elm lang and I'm curious if it's possible to use Semantic UI's dropdowns in my application.  How should one approach such task? Without libraries like Semantic UI it's pretty hard to make proper dropdowns for mobile, for example, and writing all that code from scratch seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I think what you need is [ports](http://elm-lang.org/guide/interop)

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do I create a port for each dropdown and update it whenever a corresponding part of the state has been changed in `update` function? Sounds like a ton of boilerplate.

Comment: I have this issue as well, having a site already in semantic-ui.

Comment: Not Semantic UI related but a working [Bootstrap Dropdown](https://github.com/pzavolinsky/elm-bootstrap) You can also use most of CSS only party of Bootstrap with Elm (which is a lot).

Answer (score 8):

It's not a good idea. Elm is pure. That means for any given state, we can generate the UI. And to programatically change the UI, the state must change.
The entire reason for using Elm is because of the belief that impurity is difficult to reason about, and purity is preferred.

jQuery makes it possible for an action to directly read & modify the UI without changing the application state. It's impure.

Thus Elm and jQuery are fundamentally at odds and you will likely get into a mess trying to get the two to work together.

Probably the easiest way to proceed is find a CSS library that doesn't require JS, that gives you a reasonable set of components to work with (e.g. http://purecss.io/) and use Elm in conjunction with that.

Comment: External libs are a pretty common use case. Shutting out tons of external libs because they are impure is not an option. You can't reinvent the wheel every day. The js ecosystem has to be usable.

Comment: @schlicht the entire philosophy of a pure language is "impure is not an option". Having said that, external mutable state can be isolated and represented as a signal, and changes to it modelled as effects and applied as tasks. But then you lose many benefits.

Comment: I slightly disagree, the aim imho is more to reduce impurity to a minimum and  only have contact with it were necessary.  Without side effects programs get rather boring. And from a practical stand point its impossible to redo everything one might need in elm.

Comment: @schlicht Every function written in Elm is pure. There is no question about more/less pure or a "minimum" amount of purity. This is not OCaml or Scala.

Comment: @z5h Sure, but the point is rewriting every existing JS library to fit the pure functions paradigm would be ridiculously time consuming. Do you suggest we write every dropdown, date picker, drag and drop list, etc. from scratch when writing in Elm? I don't see how this could be viable outside of extremely niche projects. Other functional languages that compile into JS have the ability to interop with JS libs rather seamlessly, see: ClojureScript, PureScript.

Comment: @VictorMarchuk so your argument is "it seems hard to do all that work" and "other stuff, I think, seems to make it easy"? In any case, I never said don't interop with any JS. All JS is not created equal and integrating with a native JS API needs to be considered on a case-by-case basis. jQuery is probably the worst case and that is the case I was responding to. Interop with React makes more sense as it's designed around functional paradigms. Interop with Polymer makes more sense as components could be treated as immutable and rendered every cycle: https://github.com/quephird/polymer-with-elm.

Comment: I don't like this answer. All good libraries like Ember.js, Angular and React also allow you integrate jQuery (e.g. UI Plugins) and it's also not advisable to do but doable and reinventing the wheel is bad IMHO. You also have to deal with side effects sometimes. You know coordinates sometimes only once something has been rendered. I think it is in general doable with Ports like e.g. in this [TodoMVC example](https://github.com/evancz/elm-todomvc/blob/8be8914582870d59989ce518e6c7d38f8081faaf/index.html#L18-L25). I only miss good interfaces like ComponentDidMount on React in Elm.

Comment: @therealmarv Elm is a language. Not a library. It's functionally pure on purpose. A main reason it exists and to use it is because of the belief that purity is good. Now people are upset that they can't easily mix impure things into it? What else don't you like? That you can't get a steak at a vegan restaurant?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about jQuery specifically, but Elm has a [Ports / Interop System](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html) specifically for using existing Javascript libraries and avoiding re-inventing too many wheels. I haven't use it but it might fit your needs.